# Unable to add tooltip to ExtJS5 grid's action column

Tags: extjs

I am unable to use tooltip in ExtJS grid's action column. Even the example given at
http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action does not work. Is there any other way to add a tooltip to the action column?

Answer (score 1):

Did you init quicktip?

Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the renderer to your action column and add a tooltip in the following way to the html.

```
 renderer: function (value, metadata, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store){
            metadata.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + value + '"';
            return value;
            }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @user1640256 Could you please paste a piece of code of what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your action column definition. should work.

```
            {
                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                sortable: false,
                text: 'Action',
                items: [
                    {
                        iconCls: 'fa fa-pencil',
                        getTip: function(value, metadata, record, row, col, store){
                            var toolTipOne = 'Tool Tip One';

                            if(record.get('something')){
                                toolTipOne = 'New Tool Tip';
                            }

                            return toolTipOne;
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
```